# Identify this anime - Anime about robot/mecha piloted by 2 people

Tags: anime, story-identification, movie

It was either late 90's or early 2000's.

The robot was piloted by a man and a woman. The woman was probably the daughter of the boss. The boss would sometimes additional gear from their HQ to the robot when they needed to upgrade.

The man was kinda cold and arrogant. He seemed like he didn't wanna be there. Once, after finished destroying an enemy, he decided to leave.

I had been looking for this anime since forever. I don't think it's Gundam, though.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it might be Kuro Mokuro. I saw this on Netflix in the last year.

The man was a samurai from 400 years in the past. He was in some sort of capsule. His mech needed two people to pilot it. The woman/teen was the boss's daughter, but she also looked like a princess who was the previous pilot. The enemy had tried to invade the Earth 400 years ago, and they're back to retrieve/start up the invasion again.

I hope this helps.